# Sitecore - Can't Access Content Items

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to access existing content items created by an admin user as a standard content editing user (Content Author, in sitecore terminology I believe) but I'm getting the following error:

> The security settings for the current language prevent you from seeing
>   this item. To continue, select another language from the Language
>   drop-down list on the Versions tab.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that your current user doesn't have the correct "Language Read" en "Language Write" rights on these items.

Open the access viewer, select your current User or Role and click on the "Columns" button and Check the radiobutton for the Language Read and Language Write fields.

[image]

[image]

Go to the /sitecore/system/languages item, to see the current language rights for your User or Role on this specific language

[image]

If your user doesn't have the correct rights for the current language, use the security editor to set the read/write rights on the language.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another solution/factor to consider regarding the language issue... basically, it has to do with manually changing Access Rights on items using the built-in Security Editor.  From the article:

> **Reason**: In the content editor on the Master database there is a folder  at /system/languages This folder has a new security key called
>   language:read and language:write.  By default this is assigned to
>   sitecore\everyone.  This is fine provided that only local users are
>   accessing the content editor but if you are using ad domain\everyone
>   will be default be denied.
>
> ***Solution**: Click on security and access viewer.  Navigate to /system/languages.  click on assign and assign the {your
>   domain}\everyone access to language:read and language:write.   If you
>   want to do this for a specific language you can open the folder click
>   on the language and set these access properties there.*

Reference: http://sitecoreguild.blogspot.com/2012/01/security-settings-for-current-language.html